# How to aggregate and sum deep nested arrays of same objects in MongoDB on a field

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb data as follows.

```
{
"primaryCategory": "Orders",
"sentiment": "POSITIVE",
"date": ISODate("2017-01-12T09:00:00.000Z"),
"commentDetails": [
    {
        "primaryCategory": "Products",
        "sentiment": "NEUTRAL",
        "date": ISODate("2017-01-12T09:00:00.000Z"),
        "commentDetails": [
            {
                "primaryCategory": "Orders",
                "sentiment": "NEGATIVE",
                "date": ISODate("2017-01-12T09:00:00.000Z"),
                "commentDetails": [

                ]
            },
            {
                "primaryCategory": "Responses",
                "sentiment": "POSITIVE",
                "date": ISODate("2017-01-12T09:00:00.000Z"),
                "commentDetails": [

                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "primaryCategory": "Orders",
        "sentiment": "NEUTRAL",
        "date": ISODate("2017-01-12T09:00:00.000Z"),
        "commentDetails": [
            {
                "primaryCategory": "Products",
                "sentiment": "NEGATIVE",
                "date": ISODate("2017-01-12T09:00:00.000Z"),
                "commentDetails": [

                ]
            },
            {
                "primaryCategory": "Orders",
                "sentiment": "POSITIVE",
                "date": ISODate("2017-01-12T09:00:00.000Z"),
                "commentDetails": [

                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here you can see that the below object is repeating as a nested array.

```
{
"primaryCategory": "Orders",
"sentiment": "POSITIVE",
"date": ISODate("2017-01-12T09:00:00.000Z"),
"commentDetails": []
}
```

What I am looking for is, I have to aggregate and group this nested array of similar objects to produce result like below.

```
[
{primaryCategory:"Orders",sentiment:[POSITIVE:3 /*Sum of all POSITIVE in Orders*/,NEGATIVE:5 /*Sum of all NEGATIVE in Orders*/,NEUTRAL:3 /*Sum of all NEUTRAL in Orders*/]},
{primaryCategory:"Products",sentiment:[POSITIVE:3 /*Sum of all POSITIVE in Products*/,NEGATIVE:5 /*Sum of all NEGATIVE in Products*/,NEUTRAL:3 /*Sum of all NEUTRAL in Products*/]},
{primaryCategory:"Responses",sentiment:[POSITIVE:3 /*Sum of all POSITIVE in Responses*/,NEGATIVE:5 /*Sum of all NEGATIVE in Responses*/,NEUTRAL:3 /*Sum of all NEUTRAL in Responses*/]}
]
```

So that the nested arrays are removed and the total count is taken by grouping the fields **"primaryCategory"** and **"sentiment"**

I have tried a number of times to get this working with no luck.
I am a beginner in MongoDB and some one please help me achieve this.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: how many levels of nested object can there be ?

Comment: Hi Felix,say there can be upto 10 levels.But that is not fixed.It may vary.but for time being we can put it as a 5 or 10